# C# Char permutation with repetition on large set of chars

Tags: c#, char, combinations

Hello Im trying to get all possible combinations with repetitions of given char array.
Char array consists of alphabet letters(only lower) and I need to generate strings with length of 30 or more chars.

I tried with method of many for-loops,but when I try to get all combinations of char in char array with length of string more then 5 I get out of Memory Exception.

So I created similar Method that takes only first 200000 strings,then next 2000000 and so on this was proven sucessfull but only with smaller length strings.

This was my method with length of 7 chars:

```
public static int Progress = 0;
public static ArrayList CreateRngUrl7()
        {

            ArrayList AllCombos = new ArrayList();
            int passed = 0;
            int Too = Progress + 200000;

            char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToLower().ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < alpha.Length; i++)
                for (int i1 = 0; i1 < alpha.Length; i1++)
                    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < alpha.Length; i2++)
                        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < alpha.Length; i3++)
                            for (int i4 = 0; i4 < alpha.Length; i4++)
                                for (int i5 = 0; i5 < alpha.Length; i5++)
                                    for (int i6 = 0; i6 < alpha.Length; i6++)
                                {
                                    if (passed > (Too - 200000) && passed < Too)
                                    {
                                        string word = new string(new char[] { alpha[i], alpha[i1], alpha[i2], alpha[i3], alpha[i4], alpha[i5],alpha[i6] });
                                        AllCombos.Add(word);
                                    }

                                    passed++;
                                }
            if (Too >= passed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All combinations of RNG7 were returned");
            }
            Progress = Too;
            return AllCombos;
        }
```

I tried adding 30 for-loops with in way described above so i Would get strings with lenghts of 30 but application just hangs.Is there any better way to do this? All answers would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**Can someone please just post method how it is done with larger legth strings I just want to see an example? I don't have to store that data,I just need to compare it with something and release it from memory. I used alphabet for example I don't need whole alphabet.Question was not how long it would take or how much combinations would it be!!!!!**

Comment: You want every combination of char array with a length over 30? Good luck! Do you need it any time soon?

Comment: I have access to large number of computers.I just Need an example method.

Comment: You do realize that it's going to be `30!` different strings in the end, each of length 30. That's 1.6*10^34 bytes. Unless you're google, you can't store that (if even they can)

Comment: There are 2,813,198,901,284,750,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 different 30 character strings created from the 26 letters of the alphabet. If you are able to compute a new string each microsecond it will require 89,205,951,968,694,400,000 billion years to computer them all. In comparison the age of the earth is estimated to 4.5 billion years. Good luck!

Comment: Ok, got my math wrong, it's `26!` (26 chars in the alphabet), but that's still `2.5*10^28` bytes

Comment: I took alphabet for example so someone can post a method that would not hang on large number of combinations.I just need 15 char or so string length. But I wanted to see how it's done on larger length!!

Comment: You could use the combinatorics library from http://noldorin.com/programming/CombinatoricsUtilities.cs.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an `OutOfMemoryException` because inside the loop you allocate a string and store it in an `ArrayList`. The strings have to stay in memory until the `ArrayList` is garbage collected and your loop creates more strings than you will be able to store.

If you simply want to check the string for a condition you should put the check inside the loop:

```
for ( ... some crazy loop ...) {
  var word = ... create word ...
  if (!WordPassesTest(word)) {
    Console.WriteLine(word + " failed test.");
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Then you only need storage for a single word. Of course, if the loop is crazy enough, it will not terminate before the end of the universe as we know it.

If you need to execute many nested but similar loops you can use recursion to simplify the code. Here is an example that is not incredible efficient, but at least it is simple:

```
Char[] chars = "ABCD".ToCharArray(); 

IEnumerable<String> GenerateStrings(Int32 length) {
  if (length == 0) {
    yield return String.Empty;
    yield break;
  }
  var strings = chars.SelectMany(c => GenerateStrings(length - 1), (c, s) => c + s);
  foreach (var str in strings)
    yield return str;
}
```

Calling `GenerateStrings(3)` will generate all strings of length 3 using lazy evaluation (so no additional storage is required for the strings).

Building on top of an `IEnumerable` generating your strings you can create primites to buffer and process buffers of strings. An easy solution is to using Reactive Extensions for .NET. Here you already have a `Buffer` primitive:

```
  GenerateStrings(3)
    .ToObservable()
    .Buffer(10)
    .Subscribe(list => ... ship the list to another computer and process it ...);
```

The lambda in `Subscribe` will be called with a `List<String>` with at most 10 strings (the parameter provided in the call to `Buffer`).

Unless you have an infinte number of computers you will still have to pull the computers from a pool and only recycle them back to the pool when they have finished the computation.

It should be obvious from the comments on this question that you will not be able to process 26^30 strings even if you have multiple computers at your disposal.

Comment: This was my plan to do,but If Im going to execute it on multiple pc I have to set some limit to each PC and to each thread of Application.Example:
1.PC - 1 Thread compares 0-2000000 Save number 2000000 to var
2.PC - 2 Thread compares 2000000-4000000 Save number to same var

So when new thread starts it can know that first 4000000 Lines are being checked and that it should start from 4000000 record. After Threads are full Save progress to file on network or SQL Db so another pc can take next records and so on.

Comment: Great example thank you! One more question should I use Take to put strings in array then compare or shouldi change your method slightly and ad if condition so it only return correct match.

Do you have any solution to my first comment for threading?

Comment: @user1010609: Use recursion if you don't want to write nested loops. Use `IEnumerable` to use lazy evaluation. Use primitives like `Buffer` to chop your workload into manageable parts.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! As I added to my question I used Alphabet Array as example,I really don't need that much array and string length but I was more intrested in learning how to do it on larger scale. Then agian the time of execution is the only limitation to solving something like 26^30. Maybe in far future it will be possible with some superfast computers! Anyway many thanks!

Comment: .Subscribe(list => exam) where exam is a List<string>.Im getting Error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.IList<string>>'"

Answer (score -1):

I don't have time right now to write some code but essentially if you are running out of RAM use disk.  I'm thinking along the lines of one thread running an algorithm to find the combinations and another persisting the results to disk and releasing the RAM.

Comment: I don't need to store this data.I just need to compare it with string I already have, And if it's a match it should stop. So real problem is not RAM memory.The problem is in genrating first say 100000 strings and sending it to thread for check and remembering that Loop stoped at 100000 so the next time it generates from 100000-200000. That way I would be able to execute it on multiple PC-s(storing data on Progress on network so Another pc can continue where first stopped and so on). The method I posted above would be ideal but I guess there are just too many for loops

Comment: As already mentioned, there are 26 ^ 30 combinations possible. At 30 chars per string, that's 84,395,967,038,542,377,577,758,630,888,479,145,622,241,280 bytes of storage you're going to need. Which is about 39,299,934,654,749,174,405,708,271,492,495,735 2TB hard drives. At $220 per 2TB drive (best price/GB I could find) that's the GDP of the USA for the next 579,104,618,380,059,529,405 years...

Comment: wow! I didn't stop to actually think about how much data would be produced.  It's fair to say then that another solution is required.  I don't understand the requirement enough to say anything sensible at this point, unless you are trying to crack passwords by checking the hash with the hash of each combination?

Comment: ok, so you want to use a cluster of computers to find a string that you already have? Hard to imagine that you are doing anything other than trying to crack a hash.  I'd love to help out but unless you can provide more details it's all just guess work.

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell Something along those lines..But im not interested in cracking passwords.